# How to return the callback return-type of the function in typescript and rxjs?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I made a factory function which take callback and can extend the pipeline of the subject.

How do I replace `Observable<unknown>` to get the correct type in `subscribe` function?

```
import './style.css';
console.clear();

import { of, map, tap, Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

const createSubject = <T>(
  factoryFn: ($: Observable<T>) => Observable<unknown>
) => {
  const sub = new Subject<T>();

  const r = factoryFn(sub.asObservable());

  function trigger(value: T) {
    sub.next(value);
  }

  trigger.$ = r;

  return trigger;
};

const login = createSubject<{ username: string }>(($) => {
  const temp = $.pipe(
    tap(() => {
      console.log('in subject!!!');
    }),
    map(({ username }) => ({ username, id: 1, password: 'password' }))
  );

  // typescript is know about temp type.
  // Observable<{  username: string;  id: number; password: string; }>
  return temp; // and it's returning.
});

login.$.subscribe((r) => {
  console.log({ r });
});

login({ username: 'username' });
```

I have try those types but none of them works:

```
const createSubject = <T>(
  factoryFn: ($: Observable<T>) => ReturnType<typeof factoryFn>
) => {

const createSubject = <T>(
  factoryFn: <ReturnType = U>($: Observable<T>) => U
) => {

const createSubject = <T>(
  factoryFn: <U>($: Observable<T>) => Observable<U>
) => {

const createSubject = <T>(
  factoryFn: ($: Observable<T>) => ReturnType
) => {
```

I want typescript will know about the return of the callback by itself.

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-uruave?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts)

Answer (score 1):

This pretty much tells compiler to forget caring about returned observable type:

```js
factoryFn: ($: Observable<T>) => Observable<unknown>
```

You could add a Type parameter (R) that would be linked to input(T) via the function:

```js
const createSubject = <T,R>(
  factoryFn: ($: Observable<T>) => Observable<R>
) => {
....
}
```

[StackBlitz Fork](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-ueekfc?file=index.ts)

The compiler cannot execute the code and **see types itself**. It only uses the information that **you provide it**.

Comment: The one problem with this solution is I must tell `createSubject` the expected return type. and I want typescript to figure this out for me. it is possible?

Comment: typescript can know about the return type within the callback. so why just not to use that and pass it to subscribe function? the `temp` variable typescript know about the type without execute it. so it just return this type.

Comment: >"I must tell createSubject the expected return type" ... Imagine you don't (yes, you can skip both parameters when you call `login = createSubject`), but then inside the callback body, Typescript cannot do any type checking. It cannot link R to T and both are effectively `any`, and type of `$` is `Observable<any>`.

Comment: hmmm so it not possible to return the type from callback? `const a = foo(() => 1)`. can't tell that a is a number? (without me tell typescript which type it return)